# Populating a Android ListView with MySQL data

Tags: android, mysql, listview, cursor

I want to retrieve data from a MySQL database and populate a ListView in my Android application. I've seen answers on stackoverflow that use complicated methods of retrieving the data from a MySQL database using JSON objects. Instead, is there anyway I can use something similar to a MySqliteCursor to connect to a MySQL database? Is the Cursor Android class limited to using SQLite databases? If none of these options are possible, is there an easier way to populate a ListView with MySQL data?

Comment: If you want to connect directly it's not secure...that's y it's recommended to use api

Answer (score 0):

See CursorAdapter class. It receive cursor, db column indicies and ids of widgets of view. Then it take data from db and populate corresponding fields

Comment: It looks like CursorAdapter is only compatible with SQLite, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it receive Cursor from sqlite. You can easily implement adapter for any data- just know number of rows and query row under particular index. See RecyclerView tutorial (updated listview)

Comment: How does one go from data from a MySQL database to retrieving Cursors as SQLite?

Comment: Cursor adapter use sqlite, you may want try making own adapter